# Combine similar LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a csv file with the format

LeftChoice, RightChoice, Left || Right

Where LeftChoice and RightChoice are  non-unique text strings, and Left || Right is the string that was picked.

What I want to do is get an List that contains for each element:
String, Chosen Count, Non Chosen Count.

Currently I have the following:

```
 var result = from line in file
                     let values = line.Split(',')
                     select new { Choice1 = values[0], Choice2 = values[1],  Result =  values[2].Equals("left")};


        var leftTrue = from dataSet in result
                 where dataSet.Result
                 group dataSet.Choice1 by dataSet.Choice1 into C1
                 select new { Value = C1.Key, Count = C1.Count() };


        var leftFalse = from dataSet in result
                       where !dataSet.Result
                       group dataSet.Choice1 by dataSet.Choice1 into C1
                       select new { Value = C1.Key, Count = C1.Count() };

        var rightTrue = from dataSet in result
                       where !dataSet.Result
                       group dataSet.Choice2 by dataSet.Choice2 into C2
                       select new { Value = C2.Key, Count = C2.Count() };


        var rightFalse = from dataSet in result
                        where dataSet.Result
                        group dataSet.Choice2 by dataSet.Choice2 into C2
                        select new { Value = C2.Key, Count = C2.Count() };
```

example input

```
 Fred,Cole,left
 Jill,Dave,right
 Pat,Fred,right
 Pat,Pat,left
```

example output:
would give

```
Name Chosen NotChosen
Fred   2        0
Cole   0        1
Jill   0        1
Dave   1        0
Pat    1        2
```

Comment: Could you give some input data and your expected output data?

Comment: edited my question to add example input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to group by Name and then count the times the name was chosen and not chosen.

```
var result = from line in file
             let values = line.Split(',')
             let left = values[0]
             let right = values[1]
             let leftChosen = values[2].Equals("left")
             let pair = new [] 
                        { 
                            new { Name = left, IsChosen = leftChosen }, 
                            new { Name = right, IsChosen = !leftChosen } 
                        }
             from item in pair
             group item by item.Name into nameGroup
             select new 
                    {
                        Name = nameGroup.Key, 
                        ChosenCount = nameGroup.Count(x => x.IsChosen),
                        NonChosenCount = nameGroup.Count(x => !x.IsChosen)
                    };
```